# Confusion with variables in the summation and integration

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

Regarding the following sum and integration:

[image]

I don't understand the difference between **t** and .

When nΔ goes to zero the text says it becomes . But why not **t**. Aren't an arbitrary point t and  the same? I don't have such confusion with an integral such as f(x) = integral 3x dx or [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/answer-board-image/c296d0ad-3199-40aa-9f55-2455ead565b3.png).

But the equation in my question has both t and   makes me very confused.

I'm missing something fundamental here but stuck with seeing the difference. How can we grasp the difference?

Comment: $t$ is a fixed number throughout all of the above.

Comment: Which book/ what kind of book is this? The limit for $\Delta \tau$ seems very strange as the limit still contains the $\Delta \tau$ that is supposed to be zero.